# Why have private static methods?

Tags: object-oriented, class, methods, static-methods, access-modifiers

I just wanted to clear up a question I have. What is the point of having a private static method as opposed to a normal method with private visibility?

I would have thought an advantage to having a static method is that it can be called without an instance of a class, but since its private is there even a point to it being static?

The only reason I can think of is that it helps conceptually understanding the method on the class level as opposed to object level.

Comment: Yes, there's a reason.  Your public/default static methods can still call your private statics.  Whether static methods should be used at all, and when it's appropriate to use private methods of any kind, are separate questions so be careful not to mix them with this question.

Comment: Quick example - factory method used by an inner class preventing invocation by other classes (you've gotta go through the factory method to get an instance of the class).

Comment: @MattFenwick: you should post this as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make methods that do not depend on instance fields, static?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/make-methods-that-do-not-depend-on-instance-fields-static)

Comment: By making a method static, you are also saying that it does not read or write to instance variables.  A method that doesn't interact with instance variables is often easier to move and refactor to other places.

Comment: @MattFenwick Most OO languages I've used let you call private static methods from public/protected/private *instance* methods as well - useful for helper functions (although in C# I pretty much use extension methods for this now).

Comment: A public static method could call a private static method internally.

Comment: Don't forget that regardless of whether a static method is private, internal or public, it still isn't thread-safe without specific code synchronization effort on your part.

Comment: One simple case would be that other public static functions depend on it.

Comment: I like this simple video description for static. It is saying even if you make multiple instances, there is only one private static variable.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mhxp5dZOy78

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The characteristic of being static is independent of the visibility.

The reasons that you will want to have a static method (some code that does not depend on non-static members) will still be useful. But maybe you don't want anyone/anything else to use it, just your class.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I also think you're missing a key point. Most static methods have zero side effects (they're effectively functions, not methods) - that's why they're made static in the first place. The argument against them being private is "If they have no side effects, why not make them public to promote code reuse". That's the key point: when we make it private, it's usually because we want you to *reuse the entire class* that uses that private method, not just that method.

Comment: I must say I have never done that or seen that behaviour. The few times I have done it was for helper methods to public static classes.

Comment: @corsiKa: Side-effects aren't the issue.  Making a static member of a class non-private effectively promises that every future version of a class will include that same method of the same name which does the same thing.  If needs change, and a future version of the class may have no need for a method which works *exactly* like the current one does, a private method may safely be replaced with one that better fulfills the new needs of the class.  As a simple example, suppose a class needs a method which takes a string and performs substitutions like `<` to `&lt;`, etc.  When it is written...

Comment: ...the strings which it is passed are known not to contain any ampersands, and it thus does not convert `&` to `&amp;` [were I writing the code, I'd convert `&` to `&amp;` even if I didn't expect it to be necessary, but suppose it doesn't].  It it later becomes necessary to handle ampersands, but the method is public, changing it to expand `&` to `&amp;` could break outside code which performs its own `&`-to-`&amp;` substitution.  If the method is private, however, it could be fixed to handle `&` without causing problems for any outside code.

Comment: That's an interesting problem to say the least, but I don't see how it being static makes it any *more* of a problem than not being static, which is key to this issue. If we follow your logic, everything everywhere would reimplement everything because "omg, what if there's a bug or requirements change someday?"

Comment: @corsika if it's for use by itself only, then why does the class need to make it static at all? it could be an instance method just the same.

Comment: @ahnbizcad Because you run the risk of accidentally having access to variables you shouldn't. In a perfect, bug free world, then no you have no need to. But it's easy to make small mistakes.

Answer (score 35):

A fairly common reason (in Java) would be for initializing immutable field variables in a constructor by using a simple `private static` method to reduce constructor clutter.

- It is `private`: external classes should not see it.
- It is `static`: it can perform some operation, independent<sup>1</sup> of the state of the host class.

A somewhat contrived example follows...

eg:

```
public class MyClass{
    private final String concatenated;

    public MyClass(String a, String b){
        concatenated = concat(a,b);
    }

    public String getConcatenated(){
       return concatenated;
    }

    /**
    *  Concatenates two Strings as `s1---s2`
    **/
    private static final String concat(String s1, String s2){
        return String.format("%s---%s", s1, s2);
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Assuming it has no interaction with other `static` variables.</sub>

Comment: This is even more valuable when you need to pass derived (calculated) arguments to a superclass' constructor.  The `super(...)` call must be the first line of your class' constructor, so you can't declare local variables to help you work out what to pass to the super call.  However, you *can* call (private) static methods, which use as many lines as is necessary to work out the value to pass to the super constructor.

Comment: note that there's the possibility of a static initializer block

Answer (score 25):

A common use-case for a `private static` method is a utility method which is

1. only used by that one class
2. is independent of the internal state of that class

Comment: Straight to the point.

Answer (score 21):

You see that you have a few lines of code that is repeated in a lot of your methods, so you decide to extract them to a single method, as duplicated code is not good.

You make the method private as it is not designed for widespread usage and you don’t want unrelated code calling it.   (Debate this point in the comments….)

As the method does not access any instance fields, it can be make static, by making it static you make it easier to understand and maybe even a little faster.

**Then....** (Maybe now, maybe later, maybe never)

Once the method has been made static, it is **clear** that it can be moved out of the class, say to an unity class.

It is also easy to transform it into an instance method of one of its parameters, often this is where the code should be.

Comment: I like this answer, but do you have any up to date reference for this? _"and maybe even a little faster"_

Comment: @Magnilex,  The "this" pointer does not get passed to static class methods, therefore they will tend to be faster then static instance methods, unless the compiler detects the "this" is not used in the instance method (unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if I find I'm writing private static methods, I take it as an indication that there's something I should have modeled separately.

Since they're not tied to the state of a particular object instance, a collection of public and private static methods could form an entirely separate class with its own semantics & non-static methods.

(Another tip-off is if I find I have a lot of static methods (public and private) that all have a common parameter of some type, they might be better off as members of that type.)

So, to answer your question, private static methods appear when a class provides a group of related methods that are independent of an instance of that class. (...and since they're independent, they may be better off in their own class.)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of at least two reasons why you would need a static private method on a class.

1: Your instances have reason to call a static method you don't want called directly, perhaps because it shares data between all instances of your class.

2: Your public static methods have subroutines that you don't want called directly.  The method is still called without an instance, just not directly.

Of course, "it helps the class make sense" is a fine reason all on its own.

Comment: "perhaps because it shares data between all instances of your class", that would be a static variable, not a method

Answer (score 0):

Static is always better than non-static and worse than a free functions, which is worse than a pure function.

Private is always better than protected which is better than public.

'Need to know' principle.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple example I can think of is, if you want to do some processing on input arguments (or some manipulation) which are passed to main function. 
So in this case if processing is big and same functionality will not be used anywhere else it will make sense to have a private function as it will not be used/called from anywhere else + static as main is static.